# disable all button and links in a div

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I'm trying to disable all click events inside a div. I disabled the whole div, but it's not a solution for me because I have mouseEnter events I need to continue working.

The problem is it's a directive I use in different parts of my application, so this div has diferents structures and sometimes the button is "direct child" sometimes it is in a second level.

That's my tried, it works, but I found it "dirty":

```
<div #mydirective>
  <button (click)="function1()">button</button>
  <div>
    <a (click)="function2()">link</a>
  </div>
</div>

//directive ts
var children = this.element.nativeElement.children;
for (let child of children) {
  this.renderer.setAttribute(child, 'disabled', 'true'); //for button
  this.renderer.addClass(child, 'disabled'); //for links
  var grandchildren = child.children;
  for (let grandchild of grandchildren) {         
    this.renderer.setAttribute(grandchild, 'disabled', 'true');
    this.renderer.addClass(grandchild, 'disabled');
  }
}
```

I'm sure it should be easier, is there any way to find all buttons and links in my div?

Comment: Why not use a form instead. That way you can set validation logic to decide if buttons inside a form is disabled? I am assuming you have some input too.

Comment: it requires a lot of changes in my code, the idea for use a directive is make as less changes as I can. But I'm having this as an option if I can't find any other. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable all mouse clicks.. Then conditionally add a css class to that div to disable all pointer events.

In html file.

```
<div class="your-class">
  // buttons and content goes here.
</div>
```

in css/scss file.

```
.your-class {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my post, this is not an option because I need mouseEnter still working

Comment: preventing an element from being the target of mouse events by using pointer-events does not necessarily mean that mouse event listeners on that element cannot or will not be triggered. If one of the element's children has pointer-events explicitly set to allow that child to be the target of mouse events, then any events targeting that child will pass through the parent as the event travels along the parent chain, and trigger event listeners on the parent as appropriate.